# Connecting to Oracle database from XCode project

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, cocoa, oracle

Does anyone have some good resources to point to that would help us get started on writing applications in XCode that talk natively to an oracle database.

We need to create a high performance utility to do data processing that involves communicating with an oracle database. For performance reasons using the pure native drivers is preferred.

Comment: Besides using Oracle’s native API? I’m not sure if OCI is supported on Mac OS X, though.

Comment: @Bavarious - according to this OTN Download page 10g clients are supported on Mac, including OCI: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html

Comment: Not sure what would lead people to think we would not want to use Oracles native API. Reworded the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Xcode and PRO*C, check [PRO*C and Xcode 3.2, how to get it working](http://ronr.blogspot.com/2010/11/proc-and-xcode-32-how-to-get-it-working.html) It explains the integration of PRO*C in Xcode. Oracle only provides 10g clients and a hastily released, incomplete 10.2.0.4 rdbms server but you can use them to connect to all current releases of Oracle. Both PRO*C and oci are support using the clients. Both PPC and intel are supported [Instant Client Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

If interested, I will make a new blog using Xcode-4.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re familiar with ODBC, you could use that, together with an appropriate ODBC driver for Oracle (Mac OS X has [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org) installed by default).  That way you’ll be able to support other databases as well, so long as an appropriate ODBC driver is on the system.

Comment: It does not appear that the newer versions of OS/X include iODBC. Would be neat if it did!